# When will equality holds in reverse triangle inequality?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, absolute-value

Prove the reverse triangle inequality :$|z\pm w|\ge||z|-|w||$ for all $z, w \in \mathbb C$, with equality holds if and only if either $z$ or $w$ is a real multiple of another.

I have proved the inequality but not able to solve for equality.

It will be great if someone can help me in this.

What I have tried is this:

let $z=cw$ for some c $\in \mathbb R$

Consider $||z|-|w||=||cw|-|w||=||c||w|-|w||=(||c|-1|)|w|$

On the other hand: $|z-w|=|cw-w|=|(c-1)w|=(|c-1|)|w|$

from here, clearly both these are not equal if $c\lt 0$.

FORWARD PART:

Given, $|z-w|=||z|-|w||$ on squaring it and solving it, I get $Re(zw^-)=|z||w|$

And for $|z+w|=||z|-|w||$ , I get $Re(zw^-)= -|z||w|$

$w^- \;denotes\; w \;conjugate$

How to proceed further ?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but "equality iff $z$ or $w$ is a real multiple of another" doesn't seem like it can be true. For example, take $w = 3z$, then $|z+w| = 4|z|$, while $| |z| - |w|| = | |z| - |3z| | = | (|3| - 1) |z| | = 2 |z|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> equality holds if and only if either $z$ or $w$ is a real multiple of another

You just proved that $c$ needs to be $\ge 0$ when you choose the $-$ sign in $|z \pm w|$. Similarly $c \le 0$ will work for the $+$ alternative.

So for an arbitrary $c \in \mathbb R$ at least one of the inequalities will become an equality. Granted, the wording of the problem could have been better.

---

[EDIT] To answer the question about proving the forward implication. For $w = 0$ the equality holds trivially, and $w = 0 z$. Otherwise let $c = \frac{z}{w} \in \mathbb C$ so that $z = c w$.

It remains to prove that if $|c w \pm w| = ||c w| - |w||$ then $c \in \mathbb R$. Squaring both sides and canceling out the common terms gives in the end:

$$
\pm (c + \bar c) = 2 |c|
$$

But $c + \bar c = 2 Re(c)$, so $|Re(c)|=|c|$, which means $c \in \mathbb R$, thus $z = c w$ is a real multiple of $w$.

Comment: How to approach forward part ? i.e. if equality holds then one is multiple of another.

Comment: @Member If you know (or proved) the `if` part for the actual (not reverse) triangle inequality, then it follows from there.

Comment: I have added my attempt of forward part, can you please tell me how to proceed further.

Comment: @Member I edited the answer to include that part.

Comment: thanks it was an elegant proof.

Answer (score 0):

For equality to hold
$$
Re(z\bar{w})=|z||w|\implies Re\big(|z|e^{\alpha}.|w|e^{-\beta}\big)=Re\big(|z||w|e^{i(\alpha-\beta)}\big)=|z||w|\\
|z||w|\cos(\alpha-\beta)=|z||w|\implies\cos(\alpha-\beta)=1\\
\implies\alpha-\beta=0\implies\arg z=\arg w\implies z=nw
$$