# Show that $||\vec x|-|\vec y||≤|\vec x-\vec y|$. When the equality holds?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Show that $||\vec x|-|\vec y||≤|\vec x-\vec y|$. When the equality holds?

I can show the inequality. Please suggest when the equality holds?

**Attempt:** Equality holds if any one of the following conditions holds:

- if either $\vec x=\vec 0$ or $\vec y=\vec 0$,
- $\vec y=\mu\vec x$, $\mu\neq 0$

Comment: If you are in a general vector space with a  norm you cannot say when equality holds.

Comment: If $\vec x, \vec y\in \mathbb{R}^3$, is this true?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Would you suggest why in general vector space with a norm we cannot say when equality holds. Also, in case of Triangle Inequality, $|\vec x+\vec y|\leq |\vec x|+|\vec y|$, you are suggesting the same?

Comment: Hint: Square both sides and use that $|\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}| = |\vec{v}|^2$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When will equality holds in reverse triangle inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646678/when-will-equality-holds-in-reverse-triangle-inequality)